# Why doesn't desktop unlock screen accept my password?

Tags: password, unlock

To unlock a my computer after waking it from standby or screen saver I sometimes have to enter my password many times before it's accepted. What's wrong with it?

UPDATE:

NOT a wireless keyboard - a plain wired [Dell RT7D50 USB keyboard](http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/public/PKSUsoXYVu5uljYfqxrOVMPnx-u1g5sVqTeptnwwK3NWGjQ3aiv7ElU6TRTDXFOyf_xeRjbp67_9SWfRdxLJdyAJyCI5xFHoNRmfRZOnMfeyQFW71jXCoI2LXQxc5Bc9VcADaAunsCV_vMlfc0-9xVf38GdaI1oIzVgYuOiy4xNQMViXzJxQX3Ysdsrr8urseVE97A) and the laptop's built-in keyboard, same behaviour.

All the dots do appear.

Sometimes switching language to a different and back to English seems to help.

There are no problems with keyboards in any other case - only when entering the password in wakeup unlock dialogue. For example when I install applications or reconfigure something and the system asks to enter the password - it is always accepted immediately.

Comment: Is this a wireless keyboard?

Comment: by entering many times, do you mean that you type and see the dots, but the entered password isnt accepted, or you dont see the dots at all, ie there is no input?

Answer (score 1):

please check your keyboard's settings.May be changing a different setting for keyboard might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If we are dealing with a wireless keyboard my first suggestion would be to check the keyboard batteries and replace them to be sure.  Then you would be advised to repair the keyboard with the reciever in case of interference that has appeared on the channel, this is truye even if it previously worked fine as the local radio environment may have changed with new emission sources etc external to your home.

The fact it does eventually work makes me think the info being sent is getting messed up somehow thus suspecting a wireless keyboard happens more with them.  If it was a bad keyboard setting it would be consistent till the setting were changed I suspect.  The other possibility with both a wired or wireless keyboard a defective keyboard or key is possible try testing each of the keys used in the password yourself.  Perhaps by typing it out a few times is any of the letters/numers/symbols sometimes missing or altered?  If so you could try cleaning the keyboard but the chances are a replacement will be needed fortunately they are cheap.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a sticky key? This could be your problem, I had a malfunctioning 'a' on My Laptop keyboard that kept sticking. Try another Keyboard maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `Sticky Keys` enabled?

Not a physically broken key like MichealH suggested, but the software option under
System->Preferences->Keyboard, Accessibility, `Simulate simultaneous keypresses`.

I had that enabled, and was also in the habit of waking the computer by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

If that's the case, either press something else, or get in the habit of pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> two or three times, whichever works.

Answer (score 0):

If changing language helps, then it would be the language settings changing your keyboard layout. Make sure you check the same keyboard is used for both languages. For example the @ symbol on a US keyboard is different to a european keyboard. Many of the puncuation keys have also moved between layouts.

Comment: The correct layout (USA) is selected by default and indicated in the unlock window. Note that what I've said is not "changing language helps", but "changing language to a different *and then back* helps", so nothing is really meant to change, but something does.